# Read XML using pandas parsing to csv

Tags: python, pandas, xml

I have the following code to extract data from XML to CSV file, but there is an error and I don't know how to solve it.

if anyone can help, please.

```
url = "http://90.161.233.78:65519/services/user/records.xml?begin=04052022?end=06052022?var=EDSLINEEMBEDDED.Module2.VI1?var=EDSLINEEMBEDDED.Module2.API1?period=900"

s = unescape(requests.get(url).text)[5:-6]
df = pd.read_xml(s, xpath="//record/* | //dateTime")
df["field"] = df["field"].ffill()
df.to_csv('output0.csv')
```

**The Error is**

```
  doc = fromstring(
  File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 3252, in lxml.etree.fromstring
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1913, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1800, in lxml.etree._parseDoc
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1141, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDoc
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 615, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 725, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 654, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError
  File "<string>", line 1
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider reading URL without `requests` or escaping content directly into [**`pandas.read_xml()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html). Per docs, emphasis added:

> path_or_buffer: *str, path object, or file-like object*
>
> String, path object (implementing `os.PathLike[str]`), or file-like object implementing a `read()` function. The string can be any valid XML string or a path. **The string can further be a URL**. Valid URL schemes include http, ftp, s3, and file.

```py
import pandas as pd

url = (
    "http://90.161.233.78:65519/services/user/records.xml?"
    "begin=04052022?end=06052022?var=EDSLINEEMBEDDED.Module2.VI1?"
    "var=EDSLINEEMBEDDED.Module2.API1?period=900"
)

df = pd.read_xml(url, xpath="//record/* | //dateTime")

# FILL PARENT TEXT FORWARD TO CHILD ITEMS
df["dateTime"] = df["dateTime"].ffill()

# DROP UNNEEDED ROWS
df[(pd.notnull(df["id"])) & (pd.notnull(df["value"]))]

df.to_csv('output0.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks, Thanks.
I got the following data :
`dateTime,id,value
1,9052022000000000.0,EDSLINEEMBEDDED.Module2.VI1,240.944444
2,9052022000000000.0,EDSLINEEMBEDDED.Module2.API1,10.981189
4,9052022001500000.0,EDSLINEEMBEDDED.Module2.VI1,240.155556`
` 

`

But, Please if you can how I can edit the format of the DateTime column to be like 2022-05-09 00:15:00.
you can help!

Comment: Simply, convert integer timestamps with [**`pandas.to_datetime()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html).